# GoLand, debugger hangs when starting a debug session apple m1

Tags: go, goland

It doesn't hang Goland, but I can't use step into, step over and other debug buttons. When starting debugging, it prints:

```
GOPATH=/Users/a/go:/Users/a/sdk/go1.16.3 #gosetup
/Users/a/sdk/go1.16.3/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/xg/45g_0kp96gj_11cftvnq919r0000gn/T/___go_build_Mur_go -gcflags all=-N -l /Users/a/GoProjects/Main/Mur.go #gosetup
"/Users/a/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Goland/ch-0/211.7142.13/GoLand.app/Contents/plugins/go/lib/dlv/macarm/dlv" --listen=0.0.0.0:54550 --headless=true --api-version=2 --check-go-version=false --only-same-user=false exec /private/var/folders/xg/45g_0kp96gj_11cftvnq919r0000gn/T/___go_build_Mur_go --
API server listening at: [::]:54550
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1205.0.27
 for arm64.
Got a connection, launched process /private/var/folders/xg/45g_0kp96gj_11cftvnq919r0000gn/T/___go_build_Mur_go (pid = 97777).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue, please see [GO-11011](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-11011).

You can download GoLand Nightly via [Toolbox App](http://toolbox.app) with the fix or compile Delve manually and specify a path to it, please see the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2436#issuecomment-835196854).